# Finding the agent's status when console and agents are running in different machines

Tags: console, agent, grinder

i am new to grinder.I want the id of the agent connected to the console in grinder.If i use the same machine both as console and agent then i can use **"agents/status"** command but if agent is another machine and is trying to connect to the console what should i be changing in the property file.I tried changing the **hostname** to the **console's ip address**.I get bind error.

Answer (score 0):

I think i faced a similar problem. Check this out. Hope this helps

http://grinder.996249.n3.nabble.com/Running-multiple-agents-in-different-machines-and-a-single-console-in-another-td8734.html